# Performance Calculation with upgraded engine

Tags: flight-training, flight-planning

I have an upcoming checkride and the DPE has asked to plan a cross country flight.  The aircraft that will be used is a PA28-151; however, it has an upgraded 160hp engine.  Regarding performance calculations, should I use charts from the current -151 PoH or can I use a charts from a similar model -161 PoH?

Comment: How did you plan your previous cross countries (if any) in the same aircraft?

Comment: I usually use foreflight and don’t fly too far but the examiner will probably want planning performed manually.

Comment: The engine upgrade requires an STC. The STC should have included a flight manual supplement with updates to affected procedures, operating limitations and performance data. It won't be found in 'generic' manuals. You'll need to look at the manual in the aircraft.